# How to get value out of an object in dart

Tags: dart

With named route like this with the returned result as searchedCity in this case.

```
TextButton(
    onPressed: () async {
      var searchedCity = await Navigator.pushNamed(context,'/city',);
);
```

In the city page, after I pop this page with a list object with a value London.

```
onPressed: () {
  Navigator.pop(context, <String>['London']);
},
```

I tried to print the searchedCity variable:

```
print(searchedCity);
```

And I got this in the console. So I know that this searchedCity object is a list and this contains London inside.

```
[London]
```

Now I have this which expect input as a String.

```
weatherData = await weather.weatherDataCity(Expect a string variable);
```

I tried to created a new String variable and assigned to searchedCity as below, but not working, please give me a hint for this?

```
String cityName = searchedCity[0];
```

So the result I expect would be like this:

```
weatherData = await weather.weatherDataCity(cityName);
```

Comment: Can you log to console this:  searchedCity[0].toString(). If you got "London" in the console. You can try String cityName = searchedCity[0].toString();

Comment: Oh, it can be about null safety as well. Can you please share the error?

Comment: @HazarBelge First I tried: String cityName = searchedCity[0]. I got this error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.  I also tried as you suggested  String cityName = searchedCity[0].toString(). But still shows the same error.

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't see searchedCity as a List. Try to set searchedCity's type as List<String> instead of var. Then can you share what's happening?

Comment: well, I had to use another variable as: var theCity = searchedCity as List; Then I can assign this to the String varible as: String cityName = theCity[0]; But this seems complicated way, is there any direct way rather then this? Anyway, it works now!

Comment: Nice to hear that! I think you should be able to change the type of *searchedCity* directly when you first declare it.